WW1 artillery shell casing
Can anyone help me
 on this shell casing that was my great grandfather’s?, it’s 7 1/4” tall and 3 1/4” wide


Instead of reposting, please edit the original, it avoids cluttering the network with duplicates. Could you add physical measurements when you edit the original as you were already asked to in the comments there.
